# Meteor 0.8.3 doesn't see Typescript Sourcemaps

Tags: meteor, typescript, source-maps

When I'm using simple Node.js [reload](https://www.npmjs.org/package/reload) package as web server - everything works fine, but when I’m serving through Meteor - can't see any ts files in Sources window in Chrome.

Comment: Please elaborate, how did you setup meteor?
What does your smart.json file look like?
How exactly did you enable typescript in meteor?

Comment: I'm just added typescript-libs meteorite package for meteor.d.ts . Doing all ts-js compiling by Webstorm now, previously used tsc with --sourcemap and --Out keys, to compile into the single file. My smart.json content:

`{
  "packages": {
    "typescript-libs": {}
  }
}
`

Answer (score 0):

You also need the typescript-compiler. Install it with meteorite:

```
mrt add typescript-compiler
```

Comment: Why? I already compiled all my files to js with js.map. I checked typescript-compiler and it's slow and non configurable.

Comment: Checked typescript-compiler second time. Current version doesn't generate any source maps and compilation is super slow. Looks like i understand where is a problem - Meteor generated coffee script source maps refer to the memory location instead of disk. Strange, that Meteor doesn't replace my locations to the memory automatically.